# 3 Urns, dimes and pennies. If two of the three coins are dimes. What is the probability that the coin selected from urn I was a dime?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Problem said:

> Urns I, II and III contain three pennies and four dimes, two pennies
>   and five dimes and three pennies and one dime, respectively. One coin
>   is selected at random from each urn.
>
> (a) What is the probability that all three selected coins have the
>   same denomination?

P(a:same denomination)=(3/7)*(2/7)*(3/7)+(4/7)*(5/7)*(1/4)= 19/98

**(b) If two of the three coins are dimes, what is the probability that the coin selected from urn I was a dime?**

**My concern:** I have no clue where I am suppose to start to solve this exercise, any help will be apprecited. Thanks!

Comment: Small typo, first term should be $(3/7)(2/7)(3/4)$. For the second problem, you can do it with a "tree" calculation, or by a formal conditional probability calculation. Let $T$ be the event two out of three were dimes, and let $D$ be the event the coin from Urn I was a dime. We want $\Pr(D\mid T)$, which is $\Pr(D\cap T)/\Pr(T)$.  Which way one answers the problem for you depends on what approach is the more familiar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of the possible $7\times7\times4=196$ events, you get exactly 2 dimes in $4\times5\times3+3\times5\times1+4\times2\times1=83$ cases. Of these, a dime is selected from urn I in $4\times5\times3+4\times2\times1=68$ cases. The probability that the coin selected from urn I was a dime is then $68/83$.